# Why do I get these type errors?

Tags: tree, frege

I have a data type:

```
data Tree = Empty | Node Int Tree Tree
```

and I want function

```
nodeDepth :: Tree -> [(Int, Int)]
```

one pair for each node. The first element is label (value )and the second one is its depth.

My intention (raw code) is like :

```
nodeDepth (Node label left right) = zip nodeDepth' (Node label left right) [0]
nodeDepth' Empty _ = []
nodeDepth' (Node label left right) [level] = label : nodeDepth' (Node label left right) level : (1 + level)
```

But this does not work.

what's wrong? I am using Frege REPL

```
Error message are like :

E <console>.fr:22: t19906 occurs in type [t19906] rendering expression level{19727} untypable.

E <console>.fr:22: type error in  expression level
    type is   t19906
    used as   [t19906]

E <console>.fr:22: type error in  expression
    nodeDepth' (Node label left right) level:+ 1 level
    type is   [[t19909]]
    used as   [Int]


E <console>.fr:22: [[Int]] is not an instance of Num


E <console>.fr:20: type error in expression nodeDepth'
    type is apparently [t19961]
    used as function


H <console>.fr:20: too many or too few arguments perhaps?


E <console>.fr:20: type error in  expression Node label left right
    type is   Tree
    used as   [t19964]


E <console>.fr:20: type error in expression
    zip nodeDepth' (Node label left right)
    type is apparently [(t19961,t19964)]
    used as function


H <console>.fr:20: too many or too few arguments perhaps?


W <console>.fr:20: application of nodeDepth will diverge.
```

Comment: Frege [differs from regular Haskell](https://github.com/Frege/frege/wiki/Differences-between-Frege-and-Haskell); I think it's more appropriate to use the [tag:frege] tag instead of [tag:haskell].

Comment: You cannot get the depth of the node. You can only get its height (eg. the longest distance from the trees leaves) So what is it that you want to get?

Comment: @Zeta thanks for editing. The type errors would have been isomorphic had he used ghci. But it's ok, we care about this. :)

Comment: @Zeta I think it's worth adding the Haskell label since the issues arising in this question are just the same for Haskell as well, whereas the label frege "restricts" the publicity of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the errors consider the following line for instance:

```
nodeDepth (Node label left right) = zip nodeDepth' (Node label left right) [0]
```

since Haskell functional application associates to the left, zip takes the function nodeDepth' as its first parameter. To fix this particular error you might want to write:

```
zip (nodeDepth' (Node label left right)) [0]
```

But then you are still missing the second argument of nodeDepth', so the expression in the parenthesis just returns a function instead of a list.

Another mistake is when you define nodeDepth' for non-empty trees: your pattern matching [level] captures level as a single element and passes it to itself on the same line. This can be only resolved by assuming that level itself is a list, but that doesn't make too much sense either, since at the end of the line the addition assumes level to be of Numeric type.

```
nodeDepth' (Node label left right) [level] = label : nodeDepth' (Node label left right) level : (1 + level)
```

The following function nodeDepth iterates through the tree using depth-first search and constructs a list of the labels and the depths of the individual nodes.

```
data Tree = Empty | Node Int Tree Tree

wikiTree = Node 2 (Node 7 (Node 2 Empty Empty) (Node 6 (Node 5 Empty Empty) (Node 11 Empty Empty))) (Node 5 Empty (Node 9 (Node 4 Empty Empty) Empty))

nodeDepth :: Tree -> [(Int, Int)]
nodeDepth Empty = []
nodeDepth (Node label left right) = nodeDepthAccumulator (Node label left right) 0

nodeDepthAccumulator :: Tree -> Int -> [(Int, Int)]
nodeDepthAccumulator Empty _ = []
nodeDepthAccumulator (Node label left right) depth = (label,depth) : nodeDepthAccumulator left (depth+1) ++ nodeDepthAccumulator right (depth+1)
```

[image: The tree given by wikiTree]

Executing nodeDepth on the example wikiTree you get:

```
> nodeDepth wikiTree
> [(2, 0),(7, 1),(2, 2),(6, 2),(5, 3),(11, 3),(5, 1),(9, 2),(4, 3)]
```

as you might have expected.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
zip nodeDepth' (Node label left right) [0]
```

The `zip` function expets two lists, but neither `nodeDepth'` nor `(Node ...)` are lists. And then you apply the result (which is a list), to some other list `[0]`, this explains the second last message. I guess you meant to write

```
zip (nodeDepth' (Node label left right)) [0]
```

but even in this case there is an argument missing for nodeDepth' to make the expression in the parentheses a list.

The second definition for `nodeDepth'` is also not going to compile, for the following reasons:

- With the pattern `[level]` you match a one-element list, and call the single element `level`. Fine. But you use `level` as second argument to nodeDepth' (which is a list) and in the expression `1+level` you use it as number.
- In an expression like

  a : b : c

`c` must be a list (it isn't in your example) and `b` must not be a list, and must have the same type as `a`. But nodeDepth' is supposed to return a list. Hence, the whole RHS makes no sense at all, therefore you get so many errors.

One tip here: since you obviously don't want level to be a list, and nowhere really pass a list to nodeDepth', wouldnt it be better to just replace the pattern `[level]` with `level` ?